# Does Office 365 Developer subscription include OneDrive?

Tags: office-365, onedrive-for-business, subscriptions

I just signed in for an Office 365 Dev subscription (trial). In the admin panel, i am not seeing any options related to OneDrive. **Is OneDrive storage not included in an Office 365 Dev subscription**?

[image]

Top Navigation -
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OneDrive is part of Sharepoint so it is included. Check  your top navigation for that.

[image]

Comment: No, it's not showing in the top navigation. I have updated my ques with the screenshot. I am currently using the trial subscription.

Comment: Could you click on your name and then on AboutMe. OneDrive is usually a document library in MySite so it might be possible your MySite is not created yet and that is why it is not visible.

Comment: "AboutMe" option is not available. Only "Signed In" email, "Sign Out" and "My Settings" are available.

Answer (score 1):

To enable Onedrive in Office 365 Dev subscription, a license needs to be assigned to the user ( in this case admin). 
Steps -

1. Go to Office 365 Dashboard. Click on Assign user licenses on right side.
   [image]
2. Select the user and assign license using the panel on the right side.
   [image]

Once done, OneDrive option will be available in the top navigation bar.
 [image: One Drive option]